# Enthought Canopy Python GUI Debugger commands disabled

Tags: python, user-interface, debugging, enthought, canopy

I have installed Enthought Canopy 1.5.1.2730 and cannot for the likes of me get the GUI Debugger to work even though I have subscribed. Is this because I'm using the free version of Canopy? If not, how do I get it working?

Answer (score -1):

Appreciate your interest in Canopy's new GUI interactive Python debugger. Registering for a free account provides access to updates of the 100 free packages in the package repository. However it is not a subscription. The other 200 packages, the debugger, and the Python Essentials training videos are available to subscribers only. See https://store.enthought.com/